# "Too many Redirections (even after re-installing Ruby 2.0.0 with OpenSSL)"

Tags: ruby

I am inexperienced (ground zero) with ruby programming and am attempting to install Snorby on a laptop running Ubuntu 13.10, with Ruby 2.0.0-p247 installed with OpenSSL using RVM.

The tutorial I am following for installing Snorby is at: http://everydayiszeroday.blogspot.com/2013/01/installing-snorby-on-ubuntu-1204.html?showComment=1383320783310#c6938351151419073746

When I execute the `sudo bundle install --no-deployment --verbose`, I end up with "Too Many redirections" (partial output is provided below). In addition, I am wondering whether the rubygem path, accessed by the bundler is correct for the installed ruby version (2.0.0).

Can someone advise me what to do next?

Sample Output:

```
$ sudo bundle install --no-deployment --verbose

Updating http://github.com/postmodern/dm-is-read_only.git
Fetching from: http://rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies
HTTP Redirection
.
.
.

Fetching from: http://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/quick/Marshal.4.8/json-1.7.7-java.gemspec.rz
HTTP Redirection

Too many redirects
Bundler::HTTPError: Too many redirects
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:197:in `fetch'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:222:in `fetch'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:222:in `fetch'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:222:in `fetch'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:222:in `fetch'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:222:in `fetch'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:92:in `fetch_spec'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/remote_specification.rb:46:in `_remote_specification'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/remote_specification.rb:51:in `method_missing'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:101:in `block in __dependencies'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:98:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:98:in `__dependencies'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:68:in .
.
.
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/installer.rb:83:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/installer.rb:14:in `install'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:247:in `install'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:27:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:344:in `dispatch'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:434:in `start'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/bin/bundle:20:in `block in '
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:3:in `with_friendly_errors'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/bin/bundle:20:in `'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:19:in `'
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an outdated `rubygems`, try:

```
$ gem update --system
```

Or if you are stick with `sudo`

```
$ sudo gem update --system
```

If that command fails, try this:

```
$ sudo gem install rubygems-update
$ sudo gem update --system
```